# Term for consonant elision

Tags: terminology, phonology, vowels, consonants

What's the name for the elision of a consonant between two vowels? 
Syncope is usually used for vowel elision (resulting in consonant clusters) but what about consonant elision?  I couldn't find any term for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Syncope is actually a particular kind of rhythmically-governed vowel elision. There is no general word that refers to intervocalic consonant deletion. The closest you can get is "lenition", which often results in deletion, but is not restricted to "intervocalic", and it has other outcomes (such as /k/ → [g]).

Comment: Well then what about 'deletion'?

Comment: Likewise, "deletion" can refer to any kind of segment, in any context.